# Firebase login failure Today

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

When I login firebase using "firebase login", it shows these errors:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
                                   !             H|H|H|H|H           H__________________________________             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|§|∞|§|H           H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           H|---------------------------------|          ===============        H|---------------------------------|            /| _   _ |          H|---------------------------------|            (| O   O |)          H|---------------------------------|            /|   U   |          H-----------------------------------             |  =/  |           H              _..._/            H              _|I/|_            H      _______/| H |/_______    H     /           / /          H    |          | | /         |  H    |          ||o||          |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H   Carl Pilcher
t̷͎̳͉̯̞͗ͪͬͤ͑̋͋̋ͩͭ̉͞ę̬͍͙̤̮̰͎̼̜̣̦͉͍̤͈̤̼̝͑̆ͥ̄̉̓̂ͥ̐̀͘͡͝ͅs̵̨ͮͬ̈̓ͮ̍͐̿͂̽̄ͥ͆ ҉͚̩̟͉̳̬̖̗̣̹̲̼͓̺̖̖̕t̷̡͙͖̟̬̭̞̬͕͙̞̤̹͍͈̮͚̣͕̣͔̥̭̩̥̰̜͎̹̜̘̦̤̪͉̞͉̯̺̙̫͓̬̦̤̮͙͔̮̩̻̺͈̥͚̹̖̲̜̬̬̐̅͑̈̄̈ͫ͊ͯ̂̅̔͛͗ͭͥ̈̚̚͢͞ͅĩ̸̛͓̝͙͇͚͔̤̬̼̖͖̬̺̮͚̼̮̳͖̜̦̖͉͈̳̬̻̥̻̫͇̮̙̰͕͈̒̐̾̽ͨͧ̀͋͛͆ͯ̒ͭ̽̃͐̕͟͝                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ͈̞͍̠̳͎͉͇͕̝̣̥̲͖̬͓̰̳n̷̴̗̫̥̖̼͔͚̖̩͕̠̱͇̠̜̣̼̠̤̬̫̣̤̞͕͕̟̟̤̭̖͙͖̣̭̠̪̩̽̏͑͆ͩͅg̹̲͙͍̬̪̲̜͙͉̙͖̥̭̪̻͙̹͍̠̰̼̯̪͍̭̠͙̩̮̥̩̱̼͙̜̦͚̙͓̣͍̰͎̝ͭ͐̈́ͣ̊ͫͬ͛ͨ́̚͘͝ͅͅͅͅͅ ̵̣̯̝̜͚̯̞̯̑̄̇̃̅͑̀͑͆̋͑̿ͨ̉͑͂͌̊͜͝ͅṱ̵͍̰̫̗̤̭̻̣̬̬͔̥͈͔̥͖͉̭͈̞̯̼̤̩̘̞̝̞̭͉͉̯̭̞̣̗̠̪̤͖ͮ̑ͤͮ̍́ë̛̟̱̹̯̮̿̏̂ͧ͑̍͒̊ͯ͂̃ͬ̀͢͝                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ̮̣͔̳̳͇̝͓͔͔̞̜̺̣̦͔̘͍̼̻͚͎̪͈̝̩̹͈̝̤̘͓̻̻̰̯̘̰̺̹̼̥̙s̜̼̤͈̭̫͓̝̙̻̼͍̥̹̙̲͓̘̟̰̪̰̰̫̫͚͖̟̦̱͔̟̼͎͈̘̰̹̱̮ͣ́ͧ̊͗ͯ͋̋ͭ͌̍͋ͥ̂̚̕͘ͅt̷̶̡̛̖̱̙͈̹͚̠͓̻̮͔̱͍̬̫̹̬̲̳̥̞̻͚͕̭̮͎̙̞̫̗̺ͦͯ̇̑̉̎ͧ͑ͬ́ḭ̤̮̰̮̪̘̰͕͙̼̯͎̠͉̯̖͕̠̬͖͉̬̻͉̼̫̯̳̟̮̦͈̝̱̞͓̜̤̜̦͖̳̬̝̻͈̱̩̖̐͌̃̎̓ͣͯ͛̑ͬ̕͟͢ņ̣̟̳̤ͤ́͐͗ͯ̽̀̐̏̆ͨ́͝g                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   g̶̥̩̣̮̫͕͍̞̯̫̜͎̣̦̠̦̼͈̝̺̓ͮ̌ͥ̐̂̎̏͜ͅ ̫̯͔̹̤̹͎̙̝̟̻͙̙̙͇̬̬̜̟̫̪̥̰̙͔͕͓̎͌ͧͤ̃̏̈ͮͣ̋̏ͫͯ͋̉̔͘͜͝͞͠ͅt̴̴̞̺̯̞̪̰͎̲͓̲̭̔͗̔ͤ͐̎ͯ̎̋̈͑́̌ͨ̏̓͞eͥ́́̉̿̾͂̏ͫ ҉̩͕̖͙̜̬̼̜̣̖̟͚͔̝̳͉̳͔͓̰̜̣̤̦̖̱̗̖̖̤̫̥̰̗͓̹̰͙͔̮̗͇̬̫̯̞̫͓͈̫̼̥͕͓͡ͅͅs̮̳̬̖͕̮̺̰̯̳̜͎͉̮̖͇̜̬̖̺̼̩͉̭̗͖̖̣̥̜̪̰̦͎̥̭̲̯̮͊̌̆̀́͆̌ͥ͢͡ͅ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ̮̥̯͙̥ţ̷̺̘͇̙̪̺̤͛̒͒̃́͞i̸̅ͫͧ̾̽̏̿ͧ͊ͬͧ̂ͬ̆̉͗͐ ҉̡͚̲͔͈̘̻̙͇̙̲͇̼̬̣͓̺͕̯̞͓͉̜͍̥̲̲̖̲̮̺̼͚̟͔̖͚̭̜̰͈̖́͠ͅͅņ̧̰̳͎̦̘̩̳͙̙̪͎̙̳͍̣̜̣̟̲̻̹͓͚͕̼̥͎͔̱͓͍̞͍̮͎̯̖̠̦̻͖͒ͨ͊̽ͪ͋̈ͣ̽̋̚g̷̛̖̪̭̤͎̺͙͈̻̘̣̥̖̘̬̟̭̠̫̪̹̠̠̝͈̺͎̫̻̫̫͓͓̦̎̔̃ͪͧ̓̔̌̊̎͘̕͝ ͓̬̲̰͕͔̯̭̼̐͒͒͐͛͟͝͝͞ͅt̯͖̂ͥ̊̅̎ͥͨ̏̎̓̿ͨ͒͗̇́͘
```

Comment: For the record, you're running into https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/285 (tl;dr: the author of a central terminal library decided to destroy the library, and auto-update brought it to you) - SO isn't the right place for this. Contact Google to report the bug to them, and hopefully, they'll remove their dependency on the library. I'll clear the spam flags though, they weren't warranted, considering this is the literal error message